# Postgresql create fixed size groups of rows

Tags: postgresql

We have a table of items that each item has an invoice id.  We process this data in chunks based on invoice id (100 "invoices" at a time).  Can you assist in creating a query that will assign a group id to each set of 100 invoices (chunk).  Here's a logical example of what we wish to attain:

In this scenario, we know we have 9 rows and 5 invoices in advance.  We want to create groups that each group contains 2 invoices except the last group.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT n1.*,
       n2.r
FROM dbtable n1,
  -- Group distinct inv_ids per group of 2
  -- or any other number by changing the /2 to e.g., /4     
  (SELECT inv_id,
          ((row_number() OVER())-1)/2 AS r
   FROM
     -- Get distinct inv_ids 
     (SELECT DISTINCT inv_id AS inv_id
      FROM dbtable
      ORDER BY inv_id) n2a) n2
WHERE n1.inv_id=n2.inv_id ;
```

This query has the advantage that will select correct groups of `inv_ids` even when the inv_ids are not consecutive.

SQL fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b56e8/4)